# Django: class based view logout user if not staff

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to use the `PermissionRequiredMixin` to verify if the authenticated user is `staff` before access to page, if he isn't authenticated the view redirects the user to the login page, on this page is loaded a form from `django.contrib.auth.views.login`, ok. But if the user is authenticated and he isn't `staff`, he will not have any form on the login page when redirected.

What should I do? Logout the user if he is not staff when he try to access the staff only page? If yes, how can I do that using the `CBV` with `TemplateView`?

**View**

```python
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin
# ...
class AdminView(PermissionRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    permission_required = 'is_staff'
    template_name = 'checkout/admin.html'
```

**login URL**

```python
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
# ...
url(r'^entrar/$', login, {'template_name': 'accounts/login.html'}, name='login')
```

Comment: Does the permission_required should have the value in the format `<app_name>`.`<permission_codename>`??

Comment: @FazilZaid yeah, I was wondering about how to do that permission and i tried this way, just later I saw on the documentation the right way, but I don't know how `'is_staff'` is working well.

Comment: could you show the login view?

Comment: @FazilZaid it's a django built-in view, you can check it here https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L42

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this mixin:

```python
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, AccessMixin
from django.contrib.auth import logout

class LogoutIfNotStaffMixin(AccessMixin):
        def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if not request.user.is_staff:
                logout(request)
                return self.handle_no_permission()
            return super(LogoutIfNotStaffMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

For use it, do as follow:

```python
class AdminView(PermissionRequiredMixin, LogoutIfNotStaffMixin, TemplateView):
    permission_required = 'is_staff'
    template_name = 'checkout/admin.html'
```

This mixin verifies the `is_staff` property (User class) in dispatch method (works for `POST`, `GET` and other request methods).